# Save variables as mat files on S3

Tags: matlab, amazon-s3

I would like to save variables as mat files on s3. The [example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/work-with-remote-data.html#mw_5e11c3de-786b-42df-ba7b-c003a8aa3a38) on the official site shows "tall table" only. Maybe I can use the "system" command overstep MATLAB but I am looking for a straight forward solution.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does look like [save](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) does not support saving to remote filesystems.

You can, however, write matrices, cells, tables and timetables.

---

An example which uses [writetable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html):

```
LastName = {'Smith';'Johnson';'Williams';'Jones';'Brown'};
Age = [38;43;38;40;49];
T = table(Age,LastName)

writetable(T,'s3://.../table.txt')
```

*Note*:

> To write to a remote location, filename must contain the full path of
>   the file specified as a uniform resource locator (URL) of the form:
>
> scheme_name://path_to_file/my_file.ext

To obtain the right URL of the bucket, you can navigate to the contents of the s3 bucket, select a file in there, choose *Copy path* and remove the name of the file (e.g table.txt).

---

The alternative is, as you mentioned, a system call:

```
a = rand(5);
save('matExample','a');
system('aws s3api put-object --bucket mybucket --key=s3mat.mat --body=matExample.mat')
```

the mat file *matExample.mat* is saved as *s3.mat* on the server.